# Resaltar Primer registro obtenido de un SELECT (PHP Y MYSQL)

Tags: php, html, css, html5, php7

Quisiera resaltar de otro color el primer elemento obtenido de una consulta SQL.
los datos los muestro a través de un `While` y `mysqli_fetch_array`.

Acá parte del código.

```
$rr = $bd->query("SELECT * FROM moduloscurso where idCurso = $idCurso ORDER BY idModulo ASC LIMIT $iniciar,$regXpagina"); 

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rr, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

    echo '

        <div class="card" style="width: 200px; background-color:#9eedb4;">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="'.$row['moduloimg'].'">
        <div class="card-body">
        <h6 class="card-title">'.$row['nombreModulo'].'</h6>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush> 
        <li class="list-group-item" id="countdown"></li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <a class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm" id="caption" 
            href="empezarCurso.php?idCurso='.$row['idCurso'].'&idModulo='.$row['idModulo'].'">Empezar Módulo
            </a>
        </li>
        </ul>
        </div>

  ';
```

Sólo quiero poner en otro color el background del primer card generado todos los demás no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En esta solución:

- usamos un contador `$i` dentro del `while` para determinar cuando estemos en la primera fila
- usamos una variable `$bg` para establecer el background según el caso mediante un operador ternario que evaluará el valor del contador  `$i`
- usamos a conveniencia una variable `$html` para ir concatenando el contenido. Nótese que está todo dentro de un bloque PHP y que en la variable se escapan las comillas relativas a los elementos CSS y otros. Así se escribe todo como una sola variable, sin unir ciertos elementos con el `.` También se evitan confusiones de cadenas, escribiendo los elementos de array como `$row[moduloimg]` sin las comillas simples, lo cual es totalmente válido
- imprimimos `$html` al salir del ciclo `while`

**Código:**

```
$rr = $bd->query("SELECT * FROM moduloscurso where idCurso = $idCurso ORDER BY idModulo ASC LIMIT $iniciar,$regXpagina"); 
$i=1;
$html="";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rr, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $bg=( $i == 1 ) ? "red" : "#9eedb4";
    $html.="
        <div class=\"card\" style=\"width: 200px; background-color:$bg;\">
        <img class=\"card-img-top\" src=\"$row[moduloimg]\">
        <div class=\"card-body\">
        <h6 class=\"card-title\">$row[nombreModulo]</h6>
        </div>
        <ul class=\"list-group list-group-flush\"> 
        <li class=\"list-group-item\" id=\"countdown\"></li>
        <li class=\"list-group-item\">
            <a class=\"btn btn-outline-success btn-sm\" id=\"caption\" 
            href=\"empezarCurso.php?idCurso=$row[idCurso]&idModulo=$row[idModulo]\">Empezar Módulo
            </a>
        </li>
        </ul>
        </div>";
        $i++;
}
echo $html;
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias, muy bien explicado y funcionando de la manera en que quería :)

Comment: Hola de nuevo, me eh encontrado con un problema, como se observa en el código ocupo LIMIT para hacer una paginación de resultados. El problema es que por cada página siempre me resalta el primer registro (cosa que no quiero). Solo debe ser el primer registro de todo, aún así sean 2 o 10 paginas de registros.

Comment: @AlexeniCruz dado que la paginación nos introduciría en otro contexto, sugiero que plantees el nuevo problema en otra pregunta distinta, así tendrá mayor atención y es la norma del sitio: una pregunta por problema. Saludos.